# How do you call on/use files from outside the activity class in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I would like to create an array of images from my drawable folder in a class outside my app activity class in Android Studio. I can use the getResources() method but only in the activity. I would like to keep my code clean and organized and creating an array in my activity may get messy if I accumulate more images. Is there something similar or a way to access that getResources() method from an outside class? What I am trying to do is generate a randomized background using the images in my drawable folder. I am open to suggestions as I am a new developer and may be approaching this problem incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem:

I mistakenly thought I needed a `getResources()`-like method to store my image files in an array.

Instead I found you can simply store the files like this:

```
public class BackgroundCatalogue {
   public int[] mBackgroundCatalogue = {
        R.drawable.image1,
        R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image3,
        R.drawable.image4
   };
}
```

I ran into a problem using `getResources` in my `Activity` because I want my app to run on API 14 and higher. The workaround for this is using `ResourcesCompat` as follows:

```
Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), mBackgroundCatalogue.getBackground(), null);
backgroundImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

`getBackground` is a custom method I defined in my other class that picks a random image file stored in the array.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need an `Activity` per se to get a hold of your `Resources`. `Activity` extends from `Context`; it is `Context` that gives you access to your resources. All you need is a class that takes a `Context` if you just want to get a reference of your `Resources`.

Comment: Okay this sounds like what I need. How do I make the class take a `Context`? My class name is `BackgroundCatalogue` for example. And when I do what `context` do I input? I assume it would look something like this: `BackgroundCatalogue(Context context) {...`.

Comment: Correct, you need to pass a `Context` to `BackgroundCatalogue`'s constructor.

Comment: When I try this: `public class BackgroundCatalogue(Context context) {...` I get an error saying `'class' or 'interface' expected`. When I try this in the `Activity`: `public BackgroundCatalogue mBackgroundCatalogue = new BackgroundCatalogue(Context context);` It gives me an error on the second `context` saying `cannot resolve symbol 'context'`.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to do it by importing `android.content.res.Resources;` and then accessing the images like this:

```
Resources res = getResources();
Drawable image = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.imageName);
```

In an outside class. Your class should extend something like `View` to access the context of the MainActivity. Example:

```
public class MyClass extends View{

Resources res = getResources();
Drawable image = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.imageName);

    public MyClass(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
}
```

The `R.drawable` points to the folder that the images are in. Simply change this to R.folderName to suit your needs. This folder has to be in the res folder of your project.

Comment: I mean this statement in particular "You would have to have a class that extends something like View"

Comment: Views have a context which allows getResources to be called, you either need to pass the resources object or the context object to a generic class to allow them to access the images.

Comment: This seems to work, but not completely. Firstly, I cannot use `getDrawable()` from API 14. I feel it's important to access the masses when building an app. I am open to different point of views on this. It says I need AP1 21+ to use that method which Android Studio says <0.1% of users run. Secondly, should I leave `Context context` as is or should I be inputing something relative to my code into the second `context`?